# When I build dockerfile with tag "php:8.1.10-fpm-alpine" on jenkins, I get "make: /bin/sh: Operation not permitted" error, is there a solution?

Tags: php-8.1

Do I need to modify the base-image? Or should I upgrade the docker version?

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1.10-fpm-alpine3.16

WORKDIR /var/www/app

RUN apk update && apk add supervisor

# setting locale
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .docker-php-global-dependancies \
    # Build dependancies for Pecl \
    autoconf \
    g++ \
    make

COPY nginx/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

COPY nginx/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

ENV CONF_D_DIR /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/

RUN pecl install -o -f redis && \
    rm -rf /tmp/pear && \
    docker-php-ext-enable redis

COPY . /var/www/app
RUN cp .env.example .env && du -sh .

# install composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
ENV COMPOSER_VERSION 2.3.5

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --version=${COMPOSER_VERSION} && \
    php composer.phar --version

# composer install and dump autoload
RUN php composer.phar install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-scripts -o && \
    php composer.phar dumpautoload --optimize

# change directory permission
RUN chown -R 33:33 /var/www/app/storage /var/www/app/bootstrap/cache/
RUN chmod -R g+w /var/www/app/storage

VOLUME /var/www/app

COPY nginx/start.sh /usr/local/bin/start
RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/start

EXPOSE 9099
CMD ["start"]
```

#### Jenkins Console Output

```
...

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: patching config.h.in
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultusercejMIP/redis-6.0.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/redis -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultusercejMIP/redis-6.0.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultusercejMIP/redis-6.0.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/redis -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/php/ext  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2    -DZEND_COMPILE_DL_EXT=1 -c /tmp/pear/temp/redis/redis.c -o redis.lo  -MMD -MF redis.dep -MT redis.lo
make: /bin/sh: Operation not permitted
make: *** [Makefile:208: redis.lo] Error 127
ERROR: `make' failed
The command '/bin/sh -c pecl install -o -f redis &&     rm -rf /tmp/pear &&     docker-php-ext-enable redis' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

#### Jenkins running in pod form on kubernetes.

#### It builds normally in my local environment (Mac OS 13.5.2, Docker 24.0.5)

But it doesn't build in jenkins. (linux/amd64, Docker 20.10.7)